# IE7 CSS inheritance does not work

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I have set some style for h2 tags (color, font-size, etc.), but when I put "A" tag inside, then style becomes as link. My html:

```
<h2>
  <a class="no-decor" href="http://localhost/xxx/">Link</a>
</h2>
```

So, as You can see, I've created "no-decor" class. It should inherit h2's style for "a" tag.

```
a.no-decor {
  color:inherit;
  font-family:inherit;
  font-size:inherit;
  font-weight:inherit;
  text-decoration:inherit;
}
```

On Firefox everythig is ok, but IE still shows tag "a" style (underline text-decoration and blue color). I know, I can set some style for "h2 a", but maybe somehow it is possible to force work CSS inherit values on IE7?

P.S. On IE6 doesn't supports too.

P.P.S. There is some example in same way: http://www.brunildo.org/test/inherit.html

Answer (score 55, accepted):

No, IE has never supported `inherit` for any property - sorry. This has been fixed in >= IE8.

Whilst you could use a JavaScript fix to copy the properties from `h2` to `a`, it's probably easiest just to apply the same styling rule to both elements:

```css
h2, h2 a {
    font: something;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

You don't need to set `inherit` on text-decoration anyway, because decoration doesn't inherit from a parent into a child: the underline effect is on the parent and goes *through* the child; the child cannot remove it (modulo IE bugs). 'text-decoration: none' on the child is the right thing, unless you want potentially *two* underlines...

Comment: Internet Explorer 7 and earlier versions don’t support the value inherit for any properties other than direction and visibility.

Answer (score 16):

try

```
a.no-decor{
  color:inherit;
  //color:expression(this.parentNode.currentStyle['color']);
  text-decoration:none;
}
```

That'll get rid of your blue color and the underline. You could use a similar expression for the underline, but you'd be better off just using text-decoration:none since that's all an inherited text-decoration is gonna give you anyhow and no need to use expressions when not absolutely necessary (you'll take a performance hit when using expressions).

Comment: First time I see :expression. More elegant solution than duplicating markup or using a JS library.

Comment: I love this. It's such an edge case for me that an expression is perfect here.

Answer (score 4):

A bug's a bug and there's nothing much you can do, short of workarounds.

There's a test for inherit support [here](http://www.brunildo.org/test/inherit.html).

You can also try to use a script like [ie7-js](http://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/), which *"is a JavaScript library to make Microsoft Internet Explorer behave like a standards-compliant browser"*

Answer (score 1):

Internet Explorer <= 7   versions don’t support the value `inherit` for any properties other than `direction` and `visibility`.

Comment: As mentioned in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511066/ie7-css-inheritance-does-not-work#comment1873681_511108) on 25 Dec '09.