# HTML-CSS: Is it really necessary to use "inherit" value for the style properties in HTML design?

Tags: html, css

My question is straight: why there is "inherit" value for (almost) all the properties in HTML-CSS .. even-though all browsers support inheritance for all (as per my observation, yes, all) the properties .. 
When I asked google about it .. I could come up with a statement saying

> "Even though certain characteristics
>   are inherited automatically in CSS,
>   there may be situations in which you
>   want to ***increase the weight of the
>   inherited property***. Specifying a value
>   of inherit for any CSS property that’s
>   applied to an element will cause the
>   element to gain its parent’s computed
>   value for the property in question. By
>   specifying in the author style sheet
>   that a property should inherit its
>   value, you can increase its weight."

Now this was yet more confusing .. what is this **"increasing the weight"**?

is it something like .. trying to stay secure .. (so as to ***not to trust the browser's inbuilt capability of inheritance*** ) or to have more understandable code?       I am not clarified ..

Also some people mention that

> "Internet Explorer 7 and earlier
>   versions don’t support the value
>   inherit for any properties other than
>   direction and visibility."

if it is true .. then it drives the reason(??) for using "inherit" value yet more weak ..

Comment: Yup, looks like yet another hack added to the spec in order to keep ie functional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to the [W3C's specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#value-def-inherit) for 'inherit' value.

Excerpt:

> The 'inherit' value can be used to
>   strengthen inherited values, and it
>   can also be used on properties that
>   are not normally inherited.

To me, this is a better phrasing rather than "increase the weight of the inherited property".

As for the IE7 inherit question, check this SO post on [IE7 CSS inherit problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511066/ie7-css-inherit-problem)

**UPDATE:**
Using [K Prime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1938411/html-css-is-it-really-necessary-to-use-inherit-value-for-the-style-properties/1938432#1938432)'s sample code, here's the test I did on IE7 vs IE8/FF3.5

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
p { color: #666; }
p a { color: blue; text-decoration: underline; }
p a.inactive { color: inherit; text-decoration: none; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#">should be default</a>
<p>
<a href="#" class="inactive">should be grey</a>
<a href="#">should be blue</a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

**IE7 output:**
[image: IE7]

**IE8/FF3.5 output:**
[image: IE8/FF3.5]

So well, IE7 failed the 'inherit' test for this one.

Comment: So we can't help IE in cases like what "K Prime" (in other answer) has mentioned .. isn't it ?

Comment: I've not tried it myself on IE. "K Prime" is trying to illustrate the intended usage of 'inherit'. My hunch is, it probably won't work on IE, sorry mate.

Comment: its ok .. not really a problem .. I just wanted to be clarified with it (I am confident to try some work-around).. It has always been the problem with browsers .. that they don't follow up W3C recommendations promptly .. anyway .. thanx for the interaction :)

Comment: @infant programmer: I did the test, refer to my updated post. :)

Comment: @o.k.w, thanx for the informative post :) .. felt, Its really a handicap about IE ..

Answer (score 2):

This is used to override a previously set custom style, or undo a customisation. To clarify:

```
p { color: #666; }
p a { color: blue; text-decoration: underline; }

p a.inactive { color: inherit; text-decoration: none; }
```

All links (`a`) inside a paragraph will be blue, but this will set those with `inactive` to inherit from parent (the `p`), which will make them gray in this case.

Comment: Sadly, from experience, no - at least not on IE6, and IE7 for certain properties