# IE7 and "inherit": ignoring entire rule?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I know that IE7 doesn't support the value `inherit` for any CSS properties except `direction` and `visibility`. When a browser doesn't support a value, it should simply not apply the given declaration (that particular line). Does anyone know why IE7 doesn't use the first `ul a` color declaration, instead choosing to use the plain `a` color declaration? Is it just ignoring the entire `ul a` rule?

To be clear: in most browsers the first link is red and the second link is blue. In IE7 the first link is red, but so is the second, even though I have at least one declaration it should understand in the `ul a` rule.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Anchor Inherit Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body {
        color: #369;
    }
    a {
        color: #f00;
    }
    ul a {
        color: #369;
        color: inherit; /* this should be ignored by IE7, right? */
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>This is testing a <a href="#">red link</a> in a paragraph.</p>

    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">here is a link that should not be red</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not ignoring the entire rule; if you place other declarations they will still work.

Comment: Then why is't it using `ul a { color: #369 }` ?

Comment: I think it's overriding it with the `inherit` value. No idea why this only affects color though - if I place a valid `padding` and an invalid `padding` I don't see this behavior.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping someone had seen that behavior before and could tell me when IE does it. It's a pretty simple test :)  I really hope it's not *just* a bug with the "inherit" value.

Comment: Have you tried reversing the order? color:inherit; color:#369;

Comment: @Šime: That would defeat the purpose of `inherit` since every browser will just take the second declaration without problems.

Comment: @BoltClock But if IE7 and IE6 don't understand the `inherit` value anyway, then why use it in the first place? Why have two rules (one for modern browsers, and one for IE7/6) if you can have only one rule?

Comment: @Šime: That's a fair question, and I might end up doing it. But I asked this question for knowledge: I want to understand the IE7 bug, in case I encounter it in a situation where I don't have that flexibility.

Comment: @theazureshadow Also, be aware of the IE7 CSS hack. If you have this: `color:inherit; *color:#369;`, then modern browsers will use the first rule, and disregard the second one. IE7 and below will not understand the first rule, but then understand and use the second one. Later, when you decide to ditch support for IE7/6 you just remove the *-prefixed rules...

Comment: IE-7 ignores `inherit`. Look [here](http://www.brunildo.org/test/inherit.html).

Comment: @shadow Was your testing conclusive?

Comment: I'm satisfied; thanks for the nudge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`color` isn't the only property which doesn't ignore unsupported and invalid values.
For example `background-color` and `display` are affected too.

> Does anyone know why IE7 doesn't use
>   the first ul a color declaration,
>   instead choosing to use the plain a
>   color declaration? Is it just ignoring
>   the entire ul a rule?

Any unrecognized value (even none) will trigger the bug.
Apparently LTE IE7 discards all the color declarations *in the same rule* (even `!important` ones) if the last one contains an erroneous value.
And this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/exigi6) confirms that it effectively overrides previous declarations in the same rule too.

As an alternative you could use a [dynamic property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511066/ie7-css-inherit-problem/5571712#5571712).

Comment: interestingly while `background-color` is affected, `background` isn't, certainly using inherit could potentially be a minefield!

Comment: Hey, great testing -- your description of the bug is much more general than mine.

Comment: I would use another method for coloring links rather than use a dynamic property, I guess, but it's a good solution. I'd accept your answer now, but I haven't done enough testing to confirm it. Do you know of an authoritative source or test suite for the bug description?

Comment: @shadow You would have to test all properties to find a pattern. It would be too fastidious and that's not what you were asking for. My test confirms that the resetting takes place (it doesn't throw *all* the declarations in the same rule unless it's the last one).