# How can I nullify css property?

Tags: css

Basically I have two external css in my page.

The first `Main.css` contains all style rules but I don't have access to it, and hence I cannot modify it. I have access to a second file `Template.css` , so I need to override the `Main.css`'s values in `template.css`.

This is easy for which I have to change the value, but how do I remove a property entirely?

Like say a class `.c1` has `height: 40px;`, how do I get rid of this height property?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15901030/reset-remove-css-styles-for-element-only

Answer (score 220, accepted):

You have to reset each individual property back to its default value. It's not great, but it's the only way, given the information you've given us.

In your example, you would do:

```
.c1 {
    height: auto;
}
```

You should search for each property here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference

For [example, `height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height):

> Initial value : `auto`

Another [example, `max-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height):

> Initial value : `none`

---

In 2017, there is now another way, the `unset` keyword:

```
.c1 {
    height: unset;
}
```

Some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset

> The unset CSS keyword is the combination of the initial and inherit
>   keywords. Like these two other CSS-wide keywords, it can be applied to
>   any CSS property, including the CSS shorthand all. This keyword resets
>   the property to its inherited value if it inherits from its parent or
>   to its initial value if not. In other words, it behaves like the
>   inherit keyword in the first case and like the initial keyword in the
>   second case.

Browser support is good: http://caniuse.com/css-unset-value

Comment: +1 for the nice answer and reference. I think the link has changed to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Reference

Comment: Setting the value to auto doesn't seem to work when there is no initial value ( "initial value: none"). For example, when doing "max-width:auto;" I get a mismatched property value error. What should I do?

Comment: @user1779563 You set it to "none".

Comment: I would like to thank @simhumileco for [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43362495/405015) which I have shamelessly stolen since my answer is accepted and people may not scroll down.

Answer (score 20):

```
.c1 {
    height: unset;
}
```

The [`unset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset) value added in *CSS3* also solves this problem and **it's even more universal method than `auto` or `initial`** because it sets to every CSS property its default value and additionally its default behawior relative to its parent.

Note that `initial` value breaks aforementioned behavior.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/unset):

> Like these two other CSS-wide keywords, it can be applied to any CSS property, including the CSS shorthand [all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/all). This keyword resets the property to its inherited value if it inherits from its parent or to its initial value if not.

Answer (score 12):

> like say a class .c1 has height:40px; how do I get rid of this height property?

Sadly, you can't. CSS doesn't have a "default" placeholder.

In that case, you would reset the property using

```
 height: auto;
```

as @Ben correctly points out, in some cases, `inherit` is the correct way to go, for example when resetting the text colour of an `a` element (that property is inherited from the parent element):

```
a { color: inherit }
```

Comment: I'll give +1 to that. There is also the "inherit" value. In some contexes other than height, inherit is more appropriate.

Comment: @meo you're right. [(Related question)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511066/ie7-css-inherit-problem) that seems to mean that there are properties that can't be reset to their default in IE... what a pity

Answer (score 9):

An [`initial`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/initial_value) keyword is being added in CSS3 to allow authors to explicitly specify this initial value.

Comment: FYI: `height:initial;` doesn't appear to work in IE9.

Comment: so whats the difference between `initial` and `auto` and `unset` ?.

Answer (score 4):

I had an issue that even when I did overwrite "height" to "unset" or "initial", it behaved differently from when I removed the previous setting.

It turned out I needed to remove the min-height property too!

```
height: unset;
min-height: none
```

Edit: I tested on IE 7 and it doesn't recognize "unset", so "auto" works better".

Comment: For future readers: if "min-height: none;" doesn't work for you, try to nullify min-height property with the value 0.

Answer (score 3):

To get rid of the fixed height property you can set it to the default value:

```
height: auto;
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to provide a selector with higher [specificity](http://htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/) than the one in `Main.css`. With that selector, set the values of the properties you want to their default, e.g.

```
body .c1 {
    height: auto;
}
```

There is no "default" value that will work for all properties, you need to look up what the default is for each one and use that.