# Is there any way to disregard the styles written in parent tags?

Tags: html, css

Is there any way to disregard whatever styles written, and start from scratch for a new tag. For example, if I have written a style

```
table {
  large amount of styles..
}
```

and then I want to start a new table with no styles whatsoever with something like this

```
<table style="no style">
```

I can write a different class for new table and apply the class, but the problem is that there are so many styles to override. Is there such an attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately no, there is no way to "reset" an element. This is one reason it is recommended to not give elements over-arching styles. It can become an issue later when you want to change it. You have two options.

1. create a class instead, and give all the existing tables that class.
2. Simply override the changes in a new class for your new tables.

Comment: +1, although I'm not sure it is unfortunate - the C in CSS stands for Cascading and that is the exact behaviour at play here.

Comment: Well it is unfortunate for his request, but yes it is the intended functionality, and in the big picture its not unfortunate. This is a case of the "fix" merely being the need to look at the problem from a different perspective.

Comment: +1. I've written an answer containing details on how to implement option number two, considering the OP is dealing with a legacy application.

Comment: I think I will go with the first solution(even if it is a lot of work, it seems the right way), and tell my colleagues strictly not to write styles for a tag itself anymore(create classes for them instead). I dont know why, but many designers have this habit.

Comment: @rubyprince: I wouldn’t recommend strict blanket advice (it’s more likely to create other problems than it is to work — e.g. `<p class="paragraph">`), but it would be a great idea to explain how over-general styles caused a maintenance headache in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Nope. You’d be better off limiting your initial large style to a class:

```
table.complex-styling {
  large amount of styles..
}
```

Comment: @paul...yes...I also agree, but the problem is mine is a legacy app and I have to change the style everywhere(lots of code to change) and if I miss anyone, it will result in style breaking.

Comment: @rubyprince: sure. I think you’ll thank yourself later though — over-general styles are a maintenance bane. And if you do miss one of the tables, it’s a quick-fix when someone spots it, right? No-one’s going to lose any money because a table looks a bit wrong for a short time?

Comment: @paul..yes..I think I will go with this solution, and I believe I should tell designers to stop overwriting style for a tag itself and create a class for the changes.

Comment: @rubyprince: sure. Regarding what the initial approach with their table should have been, it does depend. You've got to consider the website as a whole (or rather every web page that the stylesheet will apply to), and decide whether you really want every table to look a certain way. That depends on what design you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @rubyprince: As a rule of thumb though, it's better to be more specific initially, even if that results in duplicated styles, because 1. styles aren't that complicated, so it doesn't matter too much if they're duplicated, and 2. it's easier to eliminate duplication later than it is to remove globally applicable styles like this (as you've just discovered).

Answer (score 3):

In your css you can use css3 pseudo selector `:not()`:

```
table:not(.no_style) {
    large amout of styles
}
```

Than those style won't apply to `table.no_style`. But browser support for css3 selectors is limited.

Comment: Great idea, but currently limited support would put me off of this - this is one of the CSS3 additions that doesn't fail gracefully in older browsers.

Comment: This is nice, but if you can control your markup as well as styling, it is better practice to go with unobtrusive CSS. Rather than creating extra markup to tell CSS not to do something, it is better to create your CSS rules in a way that follows your markup

Comment: @Jeremy B. True. I wouldn't use that in real live, I'd go with either of your solutions:)

Answer (score 2):

Just how much is a `"large amount of styles"`?

Considering this:

> @paul...yes...I also agree, but the
>   problem is mine is a legacy app and I
>   have to change the style
>   everywhere(lots of code to change) and
>   if I miss anyone, it will result in
>   style breaking. – rubyprince

Unless there's a *joke quantity*, your best bet is to override *all properties* defined on `table` to a sensible default.

To find out what the "default value" of each property is, see: [How can I nullify css property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218679/how-can-i-nullify-css-property/5218729#5218729)

A concrete example: http://jsfiddle.net/nE4qm/

```
table {
    font-size: 20px;
    color: red;
    margin: 20px;
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #000
}
.removeStupidTableCSS {
    font-size: medium;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    position: static;
    left: auto;
    text-align: left;
    border: 0
}
.myShinyNewTable {
    color: blue
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Old table</td>
    </tr>
</table>

<hr />

<table class="removeStupidTableCSS myShinyNewTable">
    <tr>
        <td>New table</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks and +1 for the reference link to your answer to another question(which includes link to css defaults) :)

Answer (score 0):

No & I wish there was.  Unfortunately, overwriting the parent's styles is the only way to go.