# Modal is too large for the content

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

I have a problem using modal. The size of the modal is too large, namely it is way too high. I need to make the modal size smaller. What do I have to do to achieve it?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Set `height` property to auto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5218679/how-can-i-nullify-css-property) to disable fixed height and optionally set [`max-height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@viewport/max-height) to whatever that suits you.

```
{
  height: auto;
  max-height: 300px;
}
```