# IE 7 not using the most specific CSS rule

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, css-selectors

I want to style all my `th` elements the same (white text on black background) apart from a couple of usages where this formatting is not wanted - in which case I add a class of `no-headers` to the table element.

```
th {background-color: #000000; color:#FFF;}
table.no-headers th {color:inherit; background-color:inherit ;border:inherit; }
```

So here is some example markup if you needed some

```
<table><tr><th>This has a black bground</th></tr></table>
<table class="no-headers"><tr><th>This inherits bground from parent</th></tr></table>
```

This works fine in IE 8/9 and FF and Chrome but not in IE 7.
IE 7 just will not use the 2nd rule - despite it being more selective.
In fact I have tried all sorts to fix this problem - all to no avail.

I have tried adding the no-headers class on the th element too

```
th {background-color: #000000; color:#FFF;}
th.no-headers {color:inherit; background-color:inherit ;border:inherit; } 

<table><tr><th class="no-headers">This inherits bground from parent</th></tr></table>
```

and even that doesn't work - I am left feeling like I am doing something really obviously stupid / wrong - but then again it works fine in other browsers!

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/511066/ie7-css-inherit-problem)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IE7 does not recognize the `inherit` keyword (except on a few obscure properties).

Your best bet is to specify the default colors manually.

Comment: Or to be crude: don't worry, you've done nothing stupid. IE7 is the one being stupid.

Answer (score 1):

According to this SO post: [IE7 CSS inheritance does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511066/ie7-css-inherit-problem) IE didn't suport inherit until IE8. So you will have to specify the color, background, and border specifically.

Answer (score 1):

IE7 does not support style inheriting. That was introduced in IE8.

See: [IE7 CSS inheritance does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511066/ie7-css-inherit-problem)

This is not a huge problem, since IE8 is a universal upgrade from IE7, unlike IE9, which is only available for Windows NT6 and above.