# Forcing child divs to use parent's style

Tags: html, css

I wanted to give all of the child's div elements a background-color of parent div. But, as I see, child divs' style overwrite parent's style even though child's did not have that property. For example,

```
<!-- Parent's div -->
<div style="background-color:#ADADAD;">
    some codes here...
    <!-- child's div -->
    <div style="position:absolute;font-size:12px; left:600px;top:100px;">
        again some codes...
    </div>
</div>
```

In here, If i delete the style of child div, it works fine. I think my problem may be solved if i did the same thing with external css file also. But, I have already done hundreds of divs exactly like this. So, is there anyway to force parent's style to child style, just for background-color?(new in css)

Comment: "I have already done hundreds of divs exactly like this..." I'm so, so sorry.

Comment: At least,I learnt something today:)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> But, as i see, chid divs' style overwrite parent's style even though child's did not have that property.

No, they just don't inherit the value by default, so they get whatever value they would otherwise have (which is usually `transparent`).

You can (in theory) get what you want with background-color: [inherit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#value-def-inherit). That has [problems in older versions of IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511066/ie7-css-inherit-problem/511108#511108) though.

Answer (score 5):

Use css selectors like this to make the background of child div's inherit from their parent:

```
Parent's div
<div id="thisparticulardiv">
some codes here...
child's div
<div class="childrendiv">
again some codes...
</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
#thisparticulardiv {
    background-color:#ADADAD;
    ...
}

#thisparticulardiv div {
    background: inherit;
    position:absolute;
    font-size:12px;
    left:600px;
    top:100px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the inherit property on the child div :

```
background:inherit

<div style="position:absolute;font-size:12px; left:600px;top:100px; background:inherit">
```